# How to draw all plots of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have a data frame representing a benchmark and I would like to produce all possible comparison plots. Here is a small example of data frame that represents my problem.

```
 df = data.frame("A"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), "B"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2), "C"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2), "D"=c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15))
```

[image]

I want to produce the following plots.

- D in function of A, when B and C are fixed. This would produce four (4) different lines, one for each couple (B,C).
- D in function of B, when A and C are fixed. This would also produce six (6) different lines.
- D in function of C, when A and B are fixed. Again, six (6) different lines.

Is there a simple way to this in R ?

For now, I don't mind that they are in different plots or not. Any representation would be ok at this point. I only need all plots to be produced, since I don't know how we want to display our results.

**Edit**

I forgot to specify in my example that the columns of the data frame do not have the same factor levels. Here is a more complete example.

```
df = data.frame("A"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), 
            "B"=c("[0,1]","[0,1]","[0,1]","[1,3]","[1,3]","[1,3]","[0,1]","[0,1]","[0,1]","[1,3]","[1,3]","[1,3]"), 
            "C"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
            "D"=c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15))
```

Using @mattek's solution, I have the following plots.
[image]

This is great. If I could remove the extra values from the x-axis and keep only the corresponding factors for each column, that would be perfect.

Comment: Are you doing this as exploratory analysis just to check relationships? or are you trying to show a model you created? Also when you say for graph one "when B and C are fixed" do you want them to be fixed at their mean?

Comment: Yes, this is exploratory for now. I want to know the impact of each parameter on D. When I say "when B and C are fixed", I mean that I want to produce a plot for each possible couple (B,C). For example, I would have 4 plots (or lines in the same plot) for "D in function of A" : (B=1,C=1), (B=2,C=1), (B=1,C=2), (B=2,C=2).

Comment: For A and B fixed and A and C fixed wouldn't there be six lines?

Comment: `facet_wrap(~ var.name, scale = "free_x")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
```

First, we melt your table:

```
df.plot = melt(df, 
               measure.vars = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
               id.vars = 'D', 
               variable.name = 'var.name', 
               value.name = 'val.abc')
```

Then, we add groupings column:

```
df.plot$grouping = rep(1:4, 3, each = 3)
```

And we are ready to plot:

```
ggplot(df.plot, aes(x = val.abc, y = D, group = as.factor(grouping))) +
  facet_wrap(~ var.name) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = var.name)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = var.name))
```

Using `facet_wrap(~ var.name, scale = "free_x")` instead would get rid of non-existant factors in every facet.

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen so far because it actually creates "D in function of A", "D in function of B" and "D in function of C". The problem I have now is that A, B and C do not have the same type, i.e. they do no have the same factor levels. I can't produce a plot. I don't know for sure that  this is the reason. I will post a different example.

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer for exploratory analysis that will show correlation between variables and also a smoothing line:

```
df = data.frame("A"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), "B"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2), "C"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2), "D"=c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15))

panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits = 2, prefix = "", cex.cor, ...)
{
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
  r <- cor(x, y)
  txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
  txt <- paste0(prefix, txt)
  if(missing(cex.cor)) cex.cor <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
  text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex.cor * r)
}

pairs(df, lower.panel = panel.smooth, upper.panel = panel.cor)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option comes from ggplot using the GGaly package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
```

this helps a lot if some of your data is a factor, using your data, lets assume that A is a factor variables

```
df = data.frame("A"=as.factor(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)), "B"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2), "C"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2), "D"=c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15))
```

then ggpairs would make boxplots instead of points, you can choose there

[image]
    ggpairs(df)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do, I would create three new variables which capture the different combinations of A, B, and C fixed:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame("A"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), 
                  "B"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2), 
                  "C"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
                  "D"=c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15))

# add variables for A-B, A-C, B-C
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate('A - B' = paste(A, '-', B),
         'A - C' = paste(A, '-', C),
         'B - C' = paste(B, '-', C))
```

Then we make the plots:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(y = D))+
  geom_line(aes(x = C, colour = `A - B`))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(dat, aes(y = D))+
  geom_line(aes(x = B, colour = `A - C`))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(dat, aes(y = D))+
  geom_line(aes(x = A, colour = `B - C`))
```

[image]